# Pass stack resource value to another account

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

I have a log group in Account A that I want to send to a kinesis stream in another account B. I am following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CrossAccountSubscriptions.html to implement it (in typescript).

In `Account B` , I have created a cross account destination :

```
const logDestination = new CrossAccountDestination(this, 'LogDestination', {
    destinationName: 'LogDestination',
    role: IAMRole,
    targetArn: kinesisStream.streamArn
});
```

In `Account A` , I am trying to create the subscription filter :

```
const filter = lambdaFunction.logGroup.addSubscriptionFilter('Filter', {
            filterPattern: pattern,
            destination: ... 
})
```

How do I reference the cross-account destination from Account B in the template in Account A so that logs from A can be sent to the destination in B?

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering `Export/ImportValue` type of references, then there is no such option. CloudFormation (CFN) **does not support** cross-region nor cross-account references of that type.

This means that you have to do basically one of the following:

- Pass values from Acc1 into Acc2 using [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html). So you do it either programmatically (create Stack 1, get its outputs, and create Stack 2 passing in the needed outputs as parameters).
- Develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) lambda function in Acc 2. The function will have permissions to query the Stack 1 in Acc 1 for its outputs, and return them into Stack 2. This can be fully automated solution, all contained within CFN.

Other solutions are also possible, e.g. using SSM Parameter Store, but the two above would be the two most commonly used from what I've seen.

Comment: I am trying to send logs from an account to a log destination in another account.
In account A, I have created ```const logDestination = new CrossAccountDestination```.
In account B, I am creating a subscription filter  ```const subscriptionFilter = lambdaFunction.logGroup.addSubscriptionFilter( 'filterName', destination: ....)```
By using CfnParameter, will I be able to send the logs from B to the destination created in A ? @marcin

Comment: @Tisha Its difficult to see what you are doing based on the comments. I think it would be better to update the question with the relevant code examples and errors, or make new questions specific to the logs problem.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the question including more details. Please take a look at it. Thank you. @Marcin

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

After creation of the CrossAccountDestination in Account B,
Instantiates both Account A and Account B in a single app.ts and take the CrossAccountDestination instantiated in Account B as input property into Account A i.e.

```
const AccountBStack = new AccountBStack(app, `Account B`, deploymentProps={....});
```

```
const AccountAStack = new AccountAStack(app, `Account A`, 
deploymentProps= {CrossAccountDestination: AccountBStack.CrossAccountDestination, ...}
);
```